# Get submitted remote form object reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

In Rails I want to know which form was last submitted via javascript (). I want to hide it on completition.

```
= simple_form_for @user, :remote => true do |f| ...
```

In jQuery I would normally do something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() { last_submitted_form = $(this) }
```

In format.js response I would write: last_submitted_form.hide();

Is there a better way to do it in rails since I also lazy load bootstrap modals with form objects and use Turbolinks gem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `ajax:*` custom events in Rails UJS (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax)

Something like in your app js code (not tested)

```
$("form").on('ajax:complete', function() { $(this).hide() });
```

should work.